# Detect which Tabpage in TabConrol is selected from another form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I detect from `Form2` which Tab is selected in `Form1`?

I have tried to use `Form1.tabcontrol.SelectedIndex`  and `Form1.tabcontrol.SelectedTab` , but it just keep showing me that the first Tab is selected.

Here is my code :

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
{
    if (form1.tabcontrol.SelectedTab == form1.secondTab)
    {
       // do stuff
    }
    else if (form1.tabcontrol.SelectedTab == form1.thirdTab)
    {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you store which tab is selected in a presenter/viewmodel class that is accessed from both forms, i.e. it is passed to the form during creation/initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a clean `Form1`. This is not the instance where you see the tab control. You need to pass the instance of `Form1` to `Form2`. Then you will see the real selected tab that you have selected.

Make an overload for the constructor in Form2, and a variable of type `Form1`:

```
private Form1 myForm1;

public Form2(Form1 f1)
{
    // initialize the form1
    myForm1 = f1;
}
```

Now when you check for the selected tab in `Form2` it will show the real selected index. But only the one that was selected before calling `form2.Show()`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
{
   if (form1.tabcontrol.SelectedTab == form1.secondTab)
   {
        // do stuff

   }
   else if (form1.tabcontrol.SelectedTab == form1.thirdTab)
   {
       // do stuff
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another possibility could be to use a `static` variable to save the index or page when the selection changes in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `Form1`:

```
public static int Tab_Index = 0;
public static TabPage Tab_Page;

private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tab_Page = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    Tab_Index = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Don't forget to hook up the event! Just double click on it in the properties window of the tab control in the designer.

in Form 2 you can use it like this:

```
Form1.Tab_Index
Form1.Tab_Page
```

This way you will have always the current value

Comment: @Bongskie I made an edit, it might be a better solution, because it allows you to have always the current selected value when you change it

Comment: Yes . It is actualy an event better solution. Big big thank you ! )

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Form1 as owner to Form2 when you instantiate it.

In Form1:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2 {Owner = this};
private void showForm2()
{
    form2.Show();
}
```

In Form2:

```
if ( ((Form1)Owner).tabcontrol.SelectedIndex == 1 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your time ! :)